# Nested Html.Action calls in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

EDIT: Obviously this is a vastly simplified version of my site and if I make a test app, with this pattern it works fine. In our real app, we are using T4MVC and this is all within an area. I'm guessing one of these factors is causing my issue...

EDIT2: All the default routes are defined and if I navigate directly to /AreaName/ControllerName/SubChild?val=123 it renders.

I have a peculiar problem with Mvc and am hoping someone can help...

I have a controller with the following action methods

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(GetModel());
}

public ActionResult Result Child(string blah)
{
   return View(GetModel(blah));
}

public ActionResult Result SubChild(int val)
{
   return View(GetModel(val));
}
```

I then have 3 razor views.

Index.cshtml

```
<div>
@Html.Action("Child", new { blah = "raaa"})
</div>
```

Child.cshtml

```
    <div>
@*ERROR HERE*@
    @Html.Action("SubChild", new { val = 123})
    </div>
```

SubChild.cshtml

```
<h1>@Model.val</h1>
```

When I navigate to / I get an exception thrown saying that 
"No route in the route table matches the supplied values." on the Html.Action calling the SubChild Action.

This is all within the same area and the same controller. If I change the markup and use Html.Partial for the call to the Child view (and construct the model and pass it in the view), it renders fine. The issue comes when I call Html.Action within a view that's already being rendered using Html.Action.

I've tried fully qualifying the action using 
/area/controller/action, specifying the controller in the Html.Action call, passing the area as a parameter in the route values and combinations of all of these.

Does anyone have any ideas what this might be? I'm assuming that you can call Html.Action in Views that are being rendered using it, I guess I might be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is to do with our areas and routing setup.

On the 2nd pass, we are losing the reference to the area in the routevaluedictionary and as such it can't find the correct route. Where we are registering the area, we need to register the correct route.

Thanks for the help with this, I've upvoted the other answers as I think they may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Well, out of the box MVC 3 has the default route parameter named `id`. Your `SubChild` action has a parameter named `val`, so that is probably the issue.

Either rename the parameter in the Action to id, or add a new route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SubChild", 
    "{controller}/SubChild/{val}", 
    new
    {
        controller = "ControllerName",
        action = "SubChild",
        val = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are your parameters really named `blah`and `val`? Because normally the first parameter is always called `id`. Check the method `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` in your `global.asax.cs`. There must be something like

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
```

That indicates how your parameters have to be named.

I think your Actions have to be like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(GetModel());
}

public ActionResult Result Child(string id)
{
    return View(GetModel(id));
}

public ActionResult Result SubChild(int id)
{
    return View(GetModel(id));
}
```

Then the code in your views has to be:
Index.cshtml

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("Child", new { id = "raaa"})
</div>
```

Child.cshtml

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("SubChild", new { id = 123})
</div>
```